# ElasticSearch: Relevancy score override by function_score

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Following is my elastic search query, I am using `function_score` to order my result in following manner:
1. First query should match to some fields (Fulltext search)
2. order result as per user current location (using gauss function)
3. give more weight to those service providers who has some recommendations (using gauss function)
4. give more preference to those service providers which has been recently reviewed (using script score)

Now (2,3,4) point ordering will be done on resulting set, but problem is whenever i am using geo location function exact matched service provider reordered and down in the listing and my query shows result those are near to users location irrespective its less matching to other documents.

Following is my query, please help me resolve this issue. Please also suggest to optimize my this scenario what is the best way to solve this issue.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 15,
  "sort": {
    "_score": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "_all",
                "query": "Parag Gadhia Parenting classes",
                "fields": [
                  "service_prrovider_name^3",
                  "location^2",
                  "category_name^5",
                  "keyword"
                ],
                "use_dis_max": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "city_id": "1"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "category.category_name": "parenting classes"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "geo_location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": "19.451624199999998",
                "lon": "72.7966481"
              },
              "offset": "20km",
              "scale": "3km"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "likes_count": {
              "origin": 3,
              "offset": "5",
              "scale": "20"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "(0.08 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(1426072330 - doc[\"reviews.created_time\"].value) + 0.05)) + 1.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is "normal", script_score will override the previous score.

You can use `_score` variable inside script to use it.

(Such as `"script": "_score * (0.08 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(1426072330 - doc[\"reviews.created_time\"].value) + 0.05)) + 1.0"`)